# Is there a way to prevent a link from being blue and underlined after it has been visited?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.nav-tab:normal, .nav-tab:visited, .nav-tab:active, .nav-tab:focus {

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

  .nav-tab:hover {

    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;

}
</style>

<a href='#' class='nav-tab first-nav-tab'>Ponies</a>
<a href='#' class='nav-tab'>Rainbows</a>
<a href='#' class='nav-tab'>Unicorns</a>
<a href='#' class='nav-tab'>Puppies</a>
<a href='#' class='nav-tab'>Flowers</a>
```

After I click the links, they end up blue and underlined. Is there any way to prevent the links from being blue and underlined after they have been visited?

Here's a video for further detail:

https://youtu.be/9wwwytO_U64

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can choose which color the visited state is. You just have a small typo:

```
.nav-tab:active;
```

should be

```
 .nav-tab:active,
```

Comment: Fixed it. However, the link is still blue and underlined whenever a cursor leaves the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `!important` on your visited link css. 
Bootstrap has a default style on it, you just need to override it.

```
.nav-tab:visited{
   color: red!important;
   text-decoration: none!important;
}
```